# Change Lightrooms default import location

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5

To transfer my photos onto the computer, I usually put my SD card into the card reader; Lightrooms import promt then opens automatically.

However, every time I have to change the destination folder from my C: drive (which is an SSD; I don't want to store RAWs there) to the desired folder on another (internal) hard drive.

Is there a way to change the default import folder, or make Lightroom remeber what I chose on the last import?

Oh, I am using Lightroom 5.

Comment: I'm not at my computer with Lightroom, but there certainly is a way to do this - mine has done it since I started using Lightroom 10 years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lightroom offers three ways to (automatically) set an import destination (I'm using Lightroom 2015.8 but I'm quite sure it worked like that before):

1. Normally Lightroom saves the destination folder if you chose 'into one folder'-Option at the 'destination' panel of the import dialog (you need to import a few pictures once though). The next time you open the import dialog your last chosen folder should be preselected (only works for copying and moving images!).
2. If this somehow doesn't work for you, you could define an import preset (https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/photo-video-import-options.html#import_using_presets). To do so, define everything from preview to destination folder (right panel) and save your settings as preset. Next time you want to import images just select the images on the left and chose your import preset. All settings, including destination, will be set liked you've defined them in your preset.
3. Last but not least, you could deactivate the auto import prompt (Edit/Preferences/General preferences - Option "Show Import Dialog When A Memory Card Is Detected") and manually import into your desired folder by right-clicking the destination folder in the library view and choosing option 'import into that folder'

(I'm not sure if the labels of the buttons are 100% correct since I'm not using Lightroom in English)

Comment: This already did it! I created a preset, which is now selected by default at every import, so it looks like I don't have to do anything there from now on. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

To change where Lightroom automatically imports copies of the original imports, Click on File tab at top left hand side of screen. Scroll down to "Auto Import" Hover over and then select "Auto Import Settings" and then select folder or other options.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  First you open your library (top right of LR interface)  Then, on the left side of the interface, under "folders" right click on the folder you want to be your import folder.  Choose "Import to this folder" on the drop down menu. Then an import window should open with the folder you chose as your import destination.  I hope that helps!